# How to get value of checkbox in express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

How I can get value of checkbox in my express app after form submit. Here is my handlebars form with checkbox init.

```
<form action="/userSpecialisation" id="selectYourSpec">
                <div id="languages">
                    <label for="russian"> <input type="checkbox" id="russian" name="russian">Russian  </label>
                    <label for="english"> <input type="checkbox" id="english" name="english">English  </label>
                    <label for="france"> <input type="checkbox" id="france" name="france">France  </label>
                    <label for="german"> <input type="checkbox" id="german" name="german">German  </label>
                    <label for="spanish"> <input type="checkbox" id="spanish" name="spanish">Spanish  </label>
                    <label for="italian"> <input type="checkbox" id="italian" name="italian">Իտալերեն  </label>
                    <label for="arabian"> <input type="checkbox" id="arabian" name="arabian">Arabic  </label>
                    <label for="persian"> <input type="checkbox" id="persian" name="persian">Farsi  </label>
                    <label for="turkish"> <input type="checkbox" id="turkish" name="turkish">Turkish  </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sectorSubDiv">
                <input type="submit" name="sectorSubmit" id="selectorsSub" class="sectorSubmit" value="Հաստատել">
            </div>
        </form>
```

I need only div with "languages" id.When user check the checkbox I need to get the language of that label. As front-end I'm using handlebars template engine. As back-end I'm using node.js express framework.Is there any way for solving this part without jquery or not?If noway it will be fine too.
Thanks for help and attention,sorry for language mistakes.

Comment: Wrong usage of checkbox. It should have  `name="language"` and the actual language in the value attribute, like `value="english"`

Comment: Front-end already created with this code. I need a way solving for this .But thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the `input` element is used incorrectly. Using what you have now, you would need to do something like the following:

```
exports.myHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    russian,
    english,
    france,
    german,
    spanish,
    italian,
    arabian,
    persian,
    turkish
  } = req.body

  // ... rest of logic
}
```

All of those values would be `undefined` anyways because you did not specify the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value) attribute. So to fix your frontend, you would need something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="russian" name="languages" value="russian">
```

Notice that `name` is set to `languages` and the `value` is `russian` for this example. So when you have multiple `name="languages"`, that is transformed into an array. So you would access them like so:

```
exports.myHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const { languages } = req.body
  languages.forEach(language => console.log(language))
}
```

This answer assumes you have configured [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: If this was the correct answer then please mark it as such.